# Trying to quickly resurrect an old Maven built project

Tags: project, build, maven

First day on a project and first day with Maven and I've already wasted a lot of time trying to get it to build.

It appears the issue is that this old project has config, POMs, etc, that have many broken URLs embedded in them. i.e. Maven generated stack traces are presenting lots of URLs that are broken when trying to download project dependencies.

I have been given only the project source which includes Maven config files. I have not been supplied with existing Maven repositories, project dependent libraries or any build environment, etc.
I have been hacking away at these files but I don't get very far with each build attempt.

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong or is this Maven config really stuck in 2008?

**Update:**

My POM really was stuck in 2008, i.e. by virtue of versioning, it is a snapshot in time while the rest of the Java world moves on.

Some of the dependencies were no longer in any repositories, most of which were defunct projects and so I've ceased to use them. I had to rewrite the entire POM. I had to spend a lot of time tweaking versions to ensure compatibility between dependencies and between plugins. After much battling; some plugins just wouldn't coexist, clobbering each other.

All in all, it was many, many hours effort...too many for this project with only one developer, and I believe I only now know enough to be dangerous. 
The good ol' IDE build system would have been a better choice in this instance.

Comment: Do your settings.xml or POMs point to remote repositories that do not exist anymore?

Comment: First take the time to learn Maven.  *"Am I doing something fundamentally wrong"*.  Yea ... see previous.

Comment: Also: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: ftr: yes.  carlspring: no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ftr's advice ([in the comments section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15223259/trying-to-quickly-resurrect-an-old-maven-built-project#comment21458176_15223259)) is right: Maven can't download certain dependencies, but that doesn't necessarily mean that those dependencies don't exist anymore. It could just be that the extra-repos section of the Maven configuration is now missing certain repositories, and/or there's some other connection issue (like bad proxy config - which may lead to you being able to access certain repos but not others).

I've been in a similar situation, and found out that while initially Maven reported errors when trying to download about 80% of the dependencies, after various tweaks on Maven's config I ended up making it download all of the dependencies (well except one which was really just a custom jar somebody did and which was fetched directly from the local file system, but that's besides the point).

Here's what I'd do:

- Of all the dependencies that Maven says it can't download, try to spot 2 or 3 which are "well know" (like maybe if it says it can't download Servlet or some Spring library, write down the exact URL's he's trying to contact for those).
- Manually check if those URL are indeed accessible (via browser). If so, make sure that the dependencies exist for the version Maven is looking for. Maybe they have been updated since the project was created, and the old version is no longer kept. In this case, 90% of the time the solution is to simply update Maven's pom to point to the new version.
- If manually checking the dependency's URL shows you that in fact the dependency exists, for the version Maven is looking for, make sure there's no proxy or some other form of internet connection "extra config" which is done for your browser, but not for Maven. If that's the case, just update Maven's config with all those extra params (proxy, proxy authentication, etc).
- If the dependency URL doesn't exist at all, try googling to see if that dependency doesn't now exist on some other repo. For example many of the JBoss dependencies (like Hibernate, etc) have changed repo location somewhere around 2007-2009. If that's the case just add the new repo to Maven's repo list (and remove the old one if it no longer exists).
- Finally, the good old shameful way to fix this is to go to a colleague which has (or had) something to do with your project at some point, and copy his local Maven repo to your machine :)